# The argument type 'StreamSubscription<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<String>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I have bolded where the error line is. I am aware that I have assigned an incorrect type here, but what type should I return based on the error above? Thank you in advance.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BaseAuth auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: **auth.authStateChanges**,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final bool loggedIn = snapshot.hasData;
          if (loggedIn == true) {
            return HomePage();
          } else {
            return LoginPage();
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've posted the answer to your question. If this works for you, please mark it as the answer using the green tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return:

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(...
```

Instead of:

```
StreamBuilder<String>
```

And change the builder to be of type User, like this:

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {...
```

And:

```
final AuthService auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
```

Docs: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html

Comment: Hello Gerry, thank you for you reply. I have tried this and am still getting an error. The error message is: The argument type 'StreamSubscription<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<User?>?

Comment: Because you need to also change:  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> ... I've updated my answer

Comment: The same error is still there. I had actually done that before you said too.

Comment: Change BaseAuth to AuthService when setting up the auth variable (see updated answer).

Comment: Your solution is correct Gerry, I just had to resolve another issue in my other code file which I did. Thanks for your help!